# Assimp duplicates Vertices

Tags: c#, opengl, assimp

I'm using the [Assimp .NET](https://www.openhub.net/p/assimp-net) library to import collada files (.dae) from Blender in my C# application. The problem is that a few vertices are imported multiple times.

Here is the code that uses a filepath to my collada-file and imports the Assimp mesh:

```
public List<Mesh> GenerateMeshes(String path)
 {
        AssimpImporter importer = new AssimpImporter();
        importer.SetConfig(new RemoveComponentConfig(ExcludeComponent.Animations | ExcludeComponent.Boneweights | ExcludeComponent.Cameras | ExcludeComponent.Colors 
            | ExcludeComponent.Lights | ExcludeComponent.Materials | ExcludeComponent.Normals | 
            ExcludeComponent.TangentBasis | ExcludeComponent.TexCoords | ExcludeComponent.Textures));

        var scene = importer.ImportFile(path, PostProcessSteps.RemoveComponent | PostProcessSteps.JoinIdenticalVertices);
        ProcessNode(scene.RootNode, scene);
        return meshes;
  }
```

As you can cee I exclude most of the components except the position coordinates. Then I use "PostProcessSteps.RemoveComponent" and "PostProcessSteps.JoinIdenticalVertices", respectively to join identical vertices.

The ProcessNode() - loads each mesh recursively:

```
private void ProcessNode(Node node, Assimp.Scene scene)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < node.MeshCount; i++)
        {
            // The node object only contains indices to index the actual objects in the scene. 
            // The scene contains all the data, node is just to keep stuff organized (like relations between nodes).
            Assimp.Mesh m = scene.Meshes[node.MeshIndices[i]];
            meshes.Add(ProcessMesh(m, node));
        }

        // After we've processed all of the meshes (if any) we then recursively process each of the children nodes
        if (node.HasChildren)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Length; i++)
            {
                ProcessNode(node.Children[i], scene);
            }
        }
    }
```

ProcessMesh() does nothing more than put all vertices and indices in a separate list:

```
 private Mesh ProcessMesh(Assimp.Mesh mesh, Node node)
    {
        // Data to fill
        List<Vector3d> vertices = new List<Vector3d>();
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < mesh.VertexCount; i++)
        {
            Vector3d vertex = new Vector3d(mesh.Vertices[i].X, mesh.Vertices[i].Y, mesh.Vertices[i].Z); // Positions
            vertices.Add(vertex);
        }

        // Now walk through each of the mesh's faces and retrieve the corresponding vertex indices.
        for (int i = 0; i < mesh.FaceCount; i++)
        {
            Face face = mesh.Faces[i];
            // Retrieve all indices of the face and store them in the indices vector
            for (int j = 0; j < face.IndexCount; j++)
                indices.Add((int)face.Indices[j]);
        }

        //node.Transform
        Mesh geoObject = new Mesh(vertices.ToArray(), indices.ToArray(), null, null);
        geoObject.ModelMatrix = Convert(node.Transform);
        return geoObject;
    }
```

Nevertheless, this works for most meshes, but not for all. For example, I have the following cone:

[image]

and the selected vertex (i.e. X: 0.84, Y:-0.55557, Z: -1.0) is stored three times in the vertex list. I checked the collada file and this vertex definitely exists only once.

Comment: This vertex must be referenced multiple times in the file, maybe i could be worth trying to find out if it is the case, and which property is duplicated. Also, have you tried exporting to different extensions to see if it's always the same ? (like using obj and 3ds for example)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I further investigated this issue and found the following solution: In Visual Studio 2015 I set "Windows Application" instead of "Class Library" as Output Type. Suddenly the duplicated vertices vanished. Unfortunately, I cannot tell the reason why the application type influences Assimp's behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some vertices which have different texture coordinates (if you have texture atlases etc), those vertices are duplicated. Maybe you are facing this particular case ?

Comment: Well, I thought with importer.SetConfig(new RemoveComponentConfig(ExcludeComponent.TexCoords)); this shouldn't matter?

Comment: I don't know for the .net version, but for the C++ version the components you want to remove must be set in another place (`#define AI_CONFIG_PP_RVC_FLAGS YourBitField`). Still according to the documentation, this should allow assimp to correctly merge duplicate vertices (since they now have only the position in common).

Comment: Thank's I'll give it a try.

Comment: This is quite old, but don't change the define `AI_CONFIG_PP_RVC_FLAGS` at all, it's actually used like this:`importer.SetPropertyInteger(AI_CONFIG_PP_RVC_FLAGS, aiComponent_BITFLAGSGOHERE)`